# Html text is not converting to Bold using PdfMake

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, react-redux, pdfmake

I'm using **pdf make** to convert HTML content to text and download as pdf.

The issue is, the text in bold tags are not getting converted properly.
Can anyone help me regarding this issue??

Please refer to the below code-

I'm storing the HTML content in an encoded string

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const dom = parser.parseFromString(
   `<!doctype html><body>${encodedStr}`,
   'text/html');
const decodedString = dom.body.textContent;
const document = { content: [{ text: decodedString, fontSize: 15, alignment: 'justify' } ], pageOrientation: 'portrait', pageSize: 'A4' };

pdfMake.createPdf(document).download(downloadFileName);


Example content i'm using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Bold text</strong></p><p><strong>I.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text in Bold</strong><br>
<p>Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<b>` instead of `<strong>`? Always check compatible tags/css with your tool as it's not same parser as in browser

Comment: it is stripping the tags

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```
   content: [{ text: decodedString, fontSize: 15, alignment: 'justify', bold: true } ]
```